# how to send c++ compiler errors to a text file in cmd

Tags: c++, windows, cmd

I'm using MinGW on my windows10 to compile c++ programs, I always send the compiling errors to my teacher through the mail, but copying output from cmd and then making a text file is always a headache.
so I wish I could automatically create a text file containing those errors!
I've googled a lot but no satisfactory answer found.
i've tried "g++ main.cpp>error.txt"
it's creating a file but without a single character even there are a lot of errors appearing on cmd screen.
please help me with that :)

Comment: try "g++ main.cpp 1>normal.txt 2>error.txt"

Comment: Search keywords: stderr and  stdout.

Comment: @bigbin Usually there's nothing in stdout

Comment: this is what I was looking for. It is not quick to find on google as it is so downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You can write

```
g++ yourfile.cpp 2> errors.txt
```

that way you are piping stderr to the file, default (>) is stdout